# How to automatically detect change in a variable so that it can be appended to another variable

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a script where suppose there are two variables `CURRENT_USER` and `USER_LIST` . Then whenever the value of `CURRENT_USER` changes it automatically gets appended to `USER_LIST`. For eg.

```
# The value of the USER_LIST should change automatically
# having to check the variable CURRENT_USER explicitly.
CURRENT_USER="U1" # USER_LIST="U1"
CURRENT_USER="U2" # USER_LIST="U1 U2"
CURRENT_USER="U3" # USER_LIST="U1 U2 U3"
CURRENT_USER="U4" # USER_LIST="U1 U2 U3 U4"
```

Please tell me if this is possible using shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about using a function to change `CURRENT_USER` rather than setting it directly?

```
switch_user() {
   CURRENT_USER=$1
   USER_LIST="${USER_LIST} ${CURRENT_USER}"
}

switch_user U1
switch_user U3
```

(the example does not check for duplicates in `USER_LIST` to keep it simple)

Comment: thanks, I was thinking about this but actually i am not setting it directly. the value of the `CURRENT_USER` is being set by a function which i am not allowed to alter. 

But I guess I will suggest this to my mates for now.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a variable being *trapped*, with

```
declare -t CURRENT_USER
```

and then use a *DEBUG* trap. See the example 12.2.3.1 [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html)

In your case, the trap would be a function, which enters the new value of `CURRENT_USER` into your list if it is not already there.

**UPDATE**

As *chepner* pointed out, you don't need to tag the variable. It is sufficient to establish a *DEBUG* trap:

```
trap 'monitor_current_user $CURRENT_USER' DEBUG
```

where monitor_current_user is a shell function which records (if necessary) a value change of this variable.

Comment: From the man page entry for `declare`: "The trace attribute has no special meaning for variables."

Comment: @chepner: Believe your eyes only. If you try it out, you will see that it works - at least in bash 4.3.42 (that's the one I tried it with). If you don't declare -t, the new value of the variable will not be available within the trap expression. You can verify it using `trap 'echo FOO=$FOO BAR=$BAR DEBUG`, and do a `declare -t` for FOO only. You will see that you get updates on FOO reflected, but not on BAR.

Comment: The trap is executed *before* each command is executed. Create the trap. Executing `FOO=3` next shows both values unset. Now executing `BAR=6` shows `FOO=3 BAR=`. Executing any other command will show `FOO=3 BAR=6`.